# MySQL -> Create table with only hours & minutes

Tags: mysql

I need to save only hours (FORMAT 24) in a column 'HORAINICIAL' of my table. I don't want YYYY/MM/DD.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `claritytractor`.`turno` (
  `IDTURNO` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CANTIDADHORAS` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HORAINICIAL` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLACION` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FECHAMODIFICACION` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDTURNO`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

This is my INSERT:

```
    INSERT INTO `claritytractor`.`turno` (`NOMBRE`, `CANTIDADHORAS`, `HORAINICIAL`, `COLACION`, `FECHAMODIFICACION`, `STATUS`) VALUES ('Normal', 8, '08:00:00', '1', '2016-12-20', '0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not storing a full date, it is best to use simpler data types to store the value, and modify the value on its way in and out.

Define your field `HORAINICIAL` as `INT` instead of `DATE`, and then use either the number of hours (e.g. 8) directly, or use `HOUR()` to convert a `DATE` value into just hours.  When extracting the time back out, it can be converted back to a timestamp given the source date if needed.

For more information on the `HOUR()` command, read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: I need to save '15:30:00', if i use hour only saves '15'.

Comment: I answered based on the wording of your question, which indicated "I need to save only hours."  In that case, using any date would suffice, and you can then strip out the rest of the date on the way out using similar datetime commands.

Comment: I typed it like FLOAT, then i used:

** hour('15:30:00') + (minute('15:30:00') / 60) **

It saves 15.5

Comment: Yes, that would work.  You could save seconds that way, as well.  Just remember to pack on the way in and unpack on the way out, if necessary.

Comment: Yes, It is only to saves it. Thanks you.